# very large size matrix in C

Tags: c++, c

(This question is answered earlier but solution is not working or I am not able to understand it!!)

I want to use large size matrix of say `2^16*2^16`.How to do that?
Here is code I used with malloc:

```
// nrows=2^16
// ncols=2^16

 int **a_matrix = (int**) malloc (nrows *sizeof(int*));

for (int i=0; i<nrows;i++)
a_matrix[i]=(int*) malloc (ncols *sizeof(int));
enter code here
```

now when I try to access `a_matrix[55000][55000]` its giving segmentation fault

I increased stack size to unlimited(with some commands) but still its not working.:(
Is there any other way to do it?

Edit: I just want to store 1/0 so even bool will work.But in that case also same problem!

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of `malloc`. Modify your code to check that before going any further.

Comment: Are you running on a 32-bit machine (CPU and OS) or a 64-bit machine?

Comment: I am able tor read value till a_matrix[54277][54277]

Comment: Just curious, is there really data in that array? Could you use some more dynamic data structure like a <map> whose key is row/col? That would only allocate data for array elements that actually have a value.

Comment: @DanielFischer even bool is not working how much memory is needed for that?

Comment: @john Depends, what's `sizeof(bool)` in your implementation?

Comment: Are most of the values 0?  If so, look into [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) implementations.

Comment: sizeof(bool) is 1. and its not sparse matrix type.I read that one..:(

Comment: @john How much RAM do you have?  An array of size 54277x54277 would use about 11GB (assuming 32-bit integers).

Comment: 2^32 * sizeof(int), int is usually 4 bytes on a 32bit system, or 17179869184 bytes total (16gB). dude, you need a sparse matrix *bigtime*

Comment: It might be best to just represent it as a function of the row and column index, if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to store booleans, using a packed bit-array would reduce the storage far enough that it would probably work. In C++, you would use a `std::vector<bool>` or a `std::bitset`; in C,

```
#include <stdint.h>

unit32_t (*a_matrix)[1<<11] = malloc((1 << 16)*sizeof *a_matrix);
```

gives you (if the `malloc` call doesn't fail) a pointer to an array of `2^16` arrays of `2^16` bits. To access a bit, use

```
((a_matrix[row][column >> 5]) >> (column & 0x1F)) & 1
```

It's probably best to make that a function

```
int bit_at(int row, int col) {
    return ((a_matrix[row][col >> 5]) >> (col & 0x1F)) & 1;
}
```

or maybe a macro.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when we already have `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset`, both of which are packed bit arrays?

Comment: Because I write C, and not C++ :) (didn't notice the C++ tag).

Comment: ok problem solved with given code but frankly i don't know how its working.Can you explain please and also can I make it for 2^18 or say 2^n inputs?Thank you very much..:)

Comment: @john The limit is the available memory. If you need `N` booleans - let `N` be a multiple of 32 for simplicity - you need an array of `N` bits, that is, for example, `N/32` `uint32_t`. To address the k-th bit, you have to look at the `k/32`-th `uint32_t`, and pick the `k%32`-th bit in that. Division by `32 = 2^5` can also be expressed by right-shifting by 5 bits, the remainder modulo 32 by bitwise and with 31. By the way, you'd better have an `& 1` in there too, I forgot that at first.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `std::vector<bool> matrix(0x10000L * 0x10000L);` and access it like this:

```
bool b = matrix[i*0x10000 + j];

matrix[i*0x10000 + j] = true;
```

This should take less than 1/8 (or is it 1/32?) of the space of your implementation.

Comment: It's giving same error with large value of i and j:segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot allocate more than 2GB(3GB on your UBUNTU) of memory on a 32 bit machine. You might have to implement your own `malloc()` and your own paging system and `vmm`.

Comment: The theoretical limit using 32-bit pointers would be 4GB, not 2GB. Some operating systems have an artificial limit lower than 4GB. (Windows is, as I recall, 2GB, but can be tweaked by boot parameters. Linux is 3GB. Others are higher, but none are greater than 4GB.)

Comment: @Robᵩ thanks for the info. 2^32 = 4GB is the actual limit, which I know. On windows its 2GB(which I can max allocate.. i have windows only :( )

Comment: FYI: http://www.oreillynet.com/windows/blog/2006/03/overcoming_the_windows_2gb_cac.html

Comment: Now that is what I didn't know. Thanks @Robᵩ